# build: can I skip creating the distribution?

Tags: python, installation, deployment, build, setuptools

I'm very new to `setuptools`, `build`, and their ancillary tools and libraries. My understanding is that a lot of the distribution workflows are articulated around pip, tarballs, wheels, and the likes.

But what I'm trying to do is to stop after creating the package, I don't want to create the tarball nor wheel. Also, I want to keep the package directory that was created. This is for testing development code in DCCs such as Maya via rapid iteration.

I didn't see any option to do that with `python -m build`. It's all or nothing. Or perhaps I'm not looking at the right tool?

Comment: I don't understand what you try to create. `package` can have different meanings in different situations. When you use `build` then `package` can means `tarballs` or `wheels`. See [Installing Packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/) - read text directly below title `Installing Packages`. You can also read [Glossary - Import Package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package)

Comment: but maybe you needs this [Build artifacts](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/flow/#build-artifacts) and `build --sdist`, BTW: `build` is a python script so you can always check source code and use part of code to create own tools to create `package`

Comment: Package in the sense of one of the intermediate outputs of setuptools. When you `build`, it first makes a directory structure in which it copies files, based on the configuration of the repo. That directory is usually under a "build" directory. Then that structure is added in its entirety to the tarball and wheel, and then removed. I want to NOT create tarball nor a wheel, and I DON'T want the temporary directory structure removed.

I did try customizing `build` for this purpose but frankly, this is incredibly difficult. The assumptions about sdist and tarball are running deep.

Comment: Another way of describing what I want is the same as running `python setup.py install`. However, that method is flagged as deprecated and `setuptools` is strongly encouraged.

Comment: `deprecated` doesn't mean you can't use it. If this can make your life simpler then use it.